# Is there a way to watch current Junit test events?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, junit

I have a few Junit tests I've built.  I am running them in Eclipse.  I have one test that has ~50 steps.  I'd like to see where the test is at and which step it's on.  I can't seem to be able to see any sort of 'in test' status for Junit 4.  You just have to wait until the test has finished or failed to see what happened.

Is there a way to see step by step what Junit is doing?

I built my scripts in Selenium IDE and it was nice being able to see each step get executed as it happened.  I exported them to Eclipse/Junit and now I just have to fire them off and blindly wait.  Seems there should be a better way to monitor the current state of the Junit test...

Comment: you could go into the debugging mode and step through or set breakpoints on places you are interested... btw over 50 steps seems a lot for a unit test

Comment: Log the steps to the console.  Sounds more like an integration test than a unit test.

Comment: @duffymo yeah you are likely right. I always get confused because the people tend to call everything "junit test" that looks like a test even a little bit.

Comment: @Rhayene yea, this is a front-end QA test for our website.. so maybe more of a validation test.  I built this test in Selenium IDE the exported to Eclipse/Junit.

Comment: @atom999 this may be important: so you only see the steps for debugging or do you want something like logging for your test that happens always when its running?

Comment: @Rhayene I don't see any steps.  I have my server (Tomcat) running in debug mode, but I cannot see any debugging steps when the Junit test is running.  Maybe I don't know where to look.  I could add console logging, but I already have comments I added in Selenium, so I'd rather not have to re-add what I already have commented.  Ultimately I just want to watch the test run (somewhere) and see where it hangs, stops, etc..

Comment: you need to run it in eclipse in debug mode too - set a breakpoint where you want to start  monitoring, rightclick on your method and choose "debug as -> junit test"

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your JUNIT class
2. Setup breakpoints for specific places you want to monitor (just right click on the line and insert breakppoint)
3. Right click > Debug As Junit